# Embed wikipedia page in WordPress?

Tags: embed

I’d like to be able to embed a wikipedia page in my website.

I know this is possible as I’ve seen it elsewhere, but despite searching here and google I can’t figure it out.

There is/was once a plugin for this but it was last updated 8, yep eight, years ago LOL
There also doesn't appear to be any way to generate embed code from wikipedia anymore.

Let’s say for example I wanted to embed this page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMQS_Miner

here:
https://www.gayundah.info/aaa-test/

How would I go about that ?

Answer (score 0):

a plugin is available, this plugin works fine.
I personally use this to embed Wiki pages.

[Plugin Link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rdp-wiki-embed/)